# Dynamic xpath in page factory appium

Tags: appium, page-factory

```
public static WebElement selectcity(String cityname)
{
     @AndroidFindBy(xpath="//android.widget.CheckedTextView[@text='"+cityname+"']") 
     WebElement city;
     return city;
}
```

Trying to select city dynamically. When used in above fashion I'm facing the below issues:

1. The value for annotation attribute AndroidFindBy.xpath must be a constant expression
2. The annotation @AndroidFindBy is disallowed for this location

Could someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Page factory doesn't support dynamic webelements

```
    Webelement elem= driver.findElememt(By.xpath("locator"));
```

Use driver.findelemtns instead

See the status , pagefactory is marked as won't fix

https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3567#

https://discuss.appium.io/t/page-factory-for-dynamic-locators/8659